# Vim regex skip delimiters

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a vim syntax file, and I'd like to match the following bit of text:

```
@[one two three four]
```

Basically, I want to match `one` and `two` as two separate matches, and I don't care about `three` and `four` (or anything after them). I also don't want to include the `@[` delimiter at the beginning of the expression.

I tried doing this with regions, like so:

```
syn region langParamOne matchgroup=langListStart start=/@\[/ end=/\s\|\]/
syn region langParamTwo matchgroup=langListStart start=/@\[\S\+\s\+/ end=/\s\|\]/
```

Unfortunately, not only does this look messy, but vim will only match one of the regions, since one contains the other.

How can I set up a match for this syntax, but not include the starting `@[` in the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
syn region langParam matchgroup=langListStart start=/@\[/ end=/\]/ contains=langParamOne,langParamTwo
syn match langParamOne /\(@\[\)\@<=\S\+/ contained
syn match langParamTwo /\(@\[\S\+\s\)\@<=\S\+/ contained
```

Comment: Ah, so vim regexes *do* support look-ahead/look-behind. Guess I missed that. Thanks a lot, it works great!

Comment: @JakeKing Not only this - it's worth noting that it supports *variable length* look-behind (as used in `langParamTwo`). This is a thing that even today many regex flavors still do not support.